# How to set value of multidimential object when name path is stored in array of unknown length?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an array of unknown length which defines the path to content I want to alter in a object.

This is what I want.

```
let updatedContent = "Hello World!";
let myArray = ["layer1","layer2","layer3"];
myObject["layer1"]["layer2"]["layer3"] = updatedContent;
```

My problem is myArray is of unknown length. What is the best way to update a value in the object?

Comment: In array `["layer1","layer2","layer3"]` are just strings that are not associated with object.

Comment: I have a file system where users can add/change files. layer1, layer2, ect represent folder names that the user created. myArray is actually a global variable that keeps track of where the user is in the file system. Hope this clarifies my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an ugly approach using a recursive function. The idea is retrieving the nested properties in sequence, calling the function recursivelly with the current level, until the end of the array:

```js
function changeObject(obj, arr, content, index = 0) {
  if (index < arr.length - 1) {
    changeObject(obj[arr[index]], arr, content, ++index);
  } else {
    obj[arr[index]] = content;
  }
};

const myObject = {
  layer1: {
    layer2: {
      layer3: "foo"
    }
  }
};

let updatedContent = "Hello World!";
let myArray = ["layer1", "layer2", "layer3"];
myObject["layer1"]["layer2"]["layer3"] = updatedContent;

changeObject(myObject, myArray, updatedContent);
console.log(myObject);
```